# Symfony2 without Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, composer-php

How can I install symfony2 without Doctrine?

I have tried removing the package using composer and uninstalling the bundle manually but I get errors always.

My application is going to get the data from a Restful WS, so I don't need Doctrine at all.

Comment: Which package of Symfony do you use? And which package of Doctrine don't you like? Have you considered that that Doctrine package is simply a needed utility for Symfony?

Comment: I didn't say that I don't like Doctrine, in this case, I'm not going to use it, I'm using the latest version of symfony(2.4), I just want to remove doctrine, thanks

Comment: what type of error u getting..?

Comment: Did you try changing `composer.json` ?

Comment: @Antimatter: I asked about the Doctrine package you want to get rid of. Can you name it? "Doctrine" does not say anything at all, because there are so many packages. Also I asked how you do install Symfony. I expected some answer like "I'm using `symfony/symfony:2.4.*` and don't want to use `doctrine/orm`."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Create a Symfony Standard Edition project with the [Symfony installer](http://symfony.com/download):

   `symfony new symfony-se`
2. Remove the `doctrine/doctrine-bundle` and `doctrine/orm` from your `composer.json`.
3. Remove the `DoctrineBundle` from a list of registered bundles in `AppKernel`.
4. Remove the `doctrine` configuration from the `app/config/config.yml`. You can also remove database related entries from the `app/config/parameters.yml.dist`.
5. Run `composer update`.

**Note** that you'll still find some of the doctrine packages installed. For example the `doctrine/annotations` library is used by Symfony to parse annotations. [Doctrine is not only an ORM](https://web.archive.org/web/20161027035742/http://jwage.com:80/post/73741567918/doctrine-is-not-just-an-orm-for-relational).

Comment: I've tried this with a SF2.3 / Propel install w. a "composer update" but I got an Exception in the DepencyInjection component: [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException] Unable to replace alias "database_connection" with "security.acl.dbal.connection". +  The service definition "database_connection" does not exist.

Comment: @lionel ACL system you apparently use relies on a doctrine connection by default: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html

Comment: thanks @JakubZalas + for Propel user > http://propelorm.org/Propel/cookbook/symfony2/the-symfony2-security-component-and-propel.html